# Sending data to php page with java

Tags: java, php

I am trying to send the POST data from java to a PHP page. However it is not working. Whatever I echo in the php page works fine but when I send data it gives- 'undefined index'
What could be the problem ?
This is my java file.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL("http://localhost/CD/user/test");
    String result = "";
    String data = "fName=" + URLEncoder.encode("Atli", "UTF-8");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        // Send the POST data
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        dataOut.writeBytes(data);
        dataOut.flush();
        dataOut.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream()));

        String g;
        while ((g = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result += g;
        }
        in.close();

    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
}
```

And here is my php controller:

```
public function test(){

    $test=$_POST['fName'];
    $all="This is a ";
    $all=$all." ".$test;
    echo $all;



}
```

When I just send a url request , I get the ouput as 'This is a'. So it is connecting to the url and everything but while sending data, it is not working. Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using different streams for posting and getting.
Your post code works fine.

replace:

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            url.openStream())); // different stream
```

with

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (connection.getInputStream ()); // same connection
```

And it should work fine.

// edit: here without any deprecated methods:

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        String line;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh ! Thank you very much ! It works fine now. Btw when I do:
in.readLine() it says that the method is deprecated in DataOutputStream and should be replaced with BufferedReader line that I originally used. So how to solve this issue ?
Also how to send POST data using bufferedReader instead of DataOutputStream. Your help is much appreciated ! :)

Comment: You are right. I added a solution without deprecated methods. As to Post using BufferedReader: I do not think that that is possible (I could be wrong, but after all it is a Reader, not a Writer)

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly specifying that you're sending data using `GET` in Java, but you're reading `POST` data in PHP.

> **Java**(16):  `connection.setRequestMethod("GET");`
>   
>   **PHP**(3):     `$test=$_POST['fName'];`

You will need to change one of them, so they both use either `POST` or `GET`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was trying it with GET. Its not working either way- GET or POST.